# Migrate nuget Packages From File Share To TeamCity Built-in

Tags: .net, teamcity, nuget-package, nuget-server

I have my nuget packages hosted on a file share, after using TeamCity I enabled the built-in nuget feed. Now comes the question, how I can migrate my old packages from file share to TeamCity so I can decommission the file share and just use the TeamCity instead?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are looking to expose 3rd party NuGet packages, you'll need to explicitly publish them as build artifacts. If you are performing a NuGet install prior to compiling your solution then the directory these are restored to should be used as the build artifacts path

e.g.

```
work\234hkj568rt34jk\packages\** =>
```

Once you've done this you'll be able to consume them from the NuGet feed by adding this as a package source inside Visual Studio

If it's just internal packages then you just need to run the build configurations and they will be exposed.

Comment: In that case I will need to have all the build configurations for these packages defined in TC, which I don't have atm. Is there away to simply copy these nuget packages to file system and accordingly they get exposed on TC nuget feed?

Comment: If you copied them onto the build agent machine, you could then set the build artifacts path to point to that directory. If you have multiple build agents on separate machines then committing these to source code would allow them to be "copied" to any machine running the build. I wouldn't normally advocate this!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!